# Minor's legal right to his personal property

Tags: property, minor, family

I am the legal guardian of my 14-year-old grandson and have been since he was 2 years old.  He has resided with his Aunt for the past 6 years.   Due to issues concerning his safety in her home, he has requested to reside with me.   I have brought him to live with me and now his Aunt is refusing to return clothing, personal items, etc. to him.  I have bought many of the items in question, my grandson has purchased some of the items himself, and many were gifts he received.

Does he have any legal rights to these personal items?  If so, what is the process to get these items back?

Answer (score 5):

### Children own their personal property

Although legal guardians may place limits on access or use.

Unless the aunt is a legal guardian she has no right to retain them. Ask for their return. If she refuses, sue for their return.